# Why its showing class not found errors?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I just cloned a git repo and ran the necessary commands to install the project.

When I access the login page "http://localhost:80/nova/login" it works. However after enter the correct credentials and submit it shows an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class '\App\User' not found
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

Also running this command:

```
/var/www # php artisan component:update
```

It shows a similar error:

```
Starting Update of All Component files

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Component' not found
```

Comment: your laravel version ?

Comment: Are your filenames correct? are they in the correct folder (check the casing)

Comment: Version 5, yes the filenames are correct in the correct folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cloning, running through these steps should fix your problem:

- run `composer install` or `npm install`.
- check that the .env file is correct.
- run `php artisan key:generate`
- Optional: `php artisan migrate`
- run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

Reload composer autloaded classes.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thanks, but same 2 error after run that command.